# Refreshing LWC Datatable using notifyRecordUpdateAvailable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, inline

Looking for some help to see what I'm missing here.  After inline editing the records in the datatable relating to this js file, the records update successfully but the datatable is not refreshing.  You can see in the handleSave method I'm trying to use refreshApex() to essentially call the wired wirePickList method again.  Unfortunately I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from "lwc";
import getOpportunityContactRoles from '@salesforce/apex/oppController.getOpportunityContactRoles';
import ROLE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityContactRole.Role';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import GO_LIVE_DATE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__Quote__c.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Go_Live_Date__c';
import DESIRED_ROSTERING_SOLUTION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__Quote__c.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Desired_Rostering_Solution__c';
import {getRecord, getFieldValue, notifyRecordUpdateAvailable } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import { updateRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { refreshApex } from "@salesforce/apex";



// const fields = [GO_LIVE_DATE_FIELD];

const columns = [
    {label: "Contact", fieldName: "contactLink", type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'ContactName' }, target: '_blank' }},
    {label: 'Role', fieldName: 'Role', type: 'picklistColumn', editable: true, typeAttributes: {
        placeholder: 'Choose Role', options: {fieldName: 'pickListOptions'},
        value: { fieldName: 'Role' },
        context: { fieldName: 'Id' } 
    }
},
    {label: "Primary", fieldName: "IsPrimary", type: 'boolean', editable: true}
];


export default class OpportunityContactRoles extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    columns = columns;
    isLoading = true;
    error;
    records;
    @track pickListOptions  = [];
    implementationContact = false;
    technicalContact = false;
    draftValues = [];
    // showMessage = false;
    dataToRefresh;

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: "$recordId", fields: [GO_LIVE_DATE_FIELD, DESIRED_ROSTERING_SOLUTION_FIELD]})
    loadFields
    
    get goLiveDate(){
      return getFieldValue(this.loadFields.data, GO_LIVE_DATE_FIELD);
  }
    get desiredRosteringSolution(){
      return getFieldValue(this.loadFields.data, DESIRED_ROSTERING_SOLUTION_FIELD);
  }

  
 
    // fetch picklist options
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "012000000000000AAA",
        fieldApiName: ROLE_FIELD
    })
    wirePickList(value) {
        this.dataToRefresh = value;
        const {data, error} = value;
        if (data) {
            this.pickListOptions = data.values;
            this.queryOppContactRoles();
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    queryOppContactRoles(){
      getOpportunityContactRoles({quoteId : this.recordId})
      .then((result) => {
        this.records = result.map((row) => {
          if(row.Role == 'Implementation Contact') {
            this.implementationContact = true;
          }
          if(row.Role == 'Technical Contact') {
            this.technicalContact = true;
          }
          return {
            ...row,
                'ContactName': row.Contact.FirstName +' ' + row.Contact.LastName,
                'contactLink': '/' + row.ContactId,
                'Role': row.Role,
                'IsPrimary': row.IsPrimary,
                'pickListOptions': this.pickListOptions
          }
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.error = error;
    });
}

  get showMessage() {
    if(!this.goLiveDate) {
      return true;
    } else if(!this.desiredRosteringSolution) {
      return true
    } else if(!this.implementationContact) {
      return true
    } else if(!this.technicalContact) {
      return true
    }
  }

  get showTable() {
    return this.records !== undefined && this.records.length > 0;
  }

  async handleSave(event){

    // Convert datatable draft values into record objects
    const records = event.detail.draftValues.slice().map((draftValue) => {
      const fields = Object.assign({}, draftValue);
      console.log('fields: ' + JSON.stringify(fields));
      return { fields };
    });

    const updatedFields = event.detail.draftValues;
    const notifyChangeIds = updatedFields.map(row => { return { "recordId": row.Id } });

    // Clear all datatable draft values
    this.draftValues = [];

    try {
      // Update all records in parallel thanks to the UI API
      const recordUpdatePromises = records.map((record) => updateRecord(record));
      Promise.all(recordUpdatePromises);
    
      // Report success with a toast
      this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
          title: "Success",
          message: "Contact Roles updated",
          variant: "success",
        }),
      );
      
      // Display fresh data in the datatable
      await refreshApex(this.dataToRefresh);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error: ' + error);
      this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
          title: "Error updating or reloading contacts",
          message: error.body.message,
          variant: "error",
        }),
      );
    }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to `refreshApex` here; the picklist values are unlikely to change. Just call the other method directly:

```
this.queryOppContactRoles();
```

Note that Promise.all doesn't wait by default. You need to either explicitly wait with `await` or use `Promise.then` to continue.

```
// results if you care about handling the results
const results = await Promise.all(recordUpdatePromises);
```

Comment: @sdfxfox thanks for the suggestion.  Still no luck with that unfortunately.  I can confirm the queryOppContactRoles() method is being called again (on Save), but the table still isn't refreshing.

Comment: are you definitely waiting to call it until after all the updates have completed?

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC - I think that's my issue.  Because the 2nd call to this.queryOppContactRoles() via handleSave() logs the same original data as when the component first loads.  It seems like it's firing before Promise.all(recordUpdatePromises); is resolved. I've tried using await this.queryOppContactRoles() as well with no luck.

Comment: @mcg123 I just noticed you're calling Promise.all expecting it to wait until everything is done--it does not. You need to either `await Promise.all(...);` or `Promise.all(...).then((...)=>{...})`

Comment: @sdfxfox - I tried both of those suggestions and I'm still seeing this strange behavior.  As soon as I click the button to call handleSave(), the inline edits get cleared out (I assume because of draftValues getting updated to [ ]).  I've even tried moving the draftValues = [ ] statement to within the .then of the promise and also after the .then entirely.

Comment: @sdfxfox and BritishBoyinDEC - got it sorted out.  I foolishly was using cacheable=true on the queryOppContactRoles() method.  Removing this annotation does the trick.  Thank you both for your suggestions!