lightning-datatable inline editing - text only?
Is it correct that the standard lightning-datatable inline editing only offers a text field? There is no way to e.g. make the editing control a picklist using that component?
If the above is wrong, please point me to the relevant documentation for how to hook in picklist editing.
(This question LWC Datatable Inline Edit for Picklist does not have a definitive answer but suggests a picklist is possible via a custom field type.)
From the comment thread, a working example: Error and Changes in Spring 24 to define Column type - Picklist with LWC Datatable and this LWC issue 4177.

I had a hard time getting picklists to work using the examples folks had posted - but with some help from support, I did get it to work eventually - solution here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/416944/error-and-changes-in-spring-24-to-define-column-type-picklist-with-lwc-datatab

Thanks @BritishBoyinDC, I'll link that directly in the question too.

@BritishBoyinDC, Having a real struggle passing the options in. I'm using a dual listbox and TypeError: this.options.filter is not a function after many tries :(.

@BritishBoyinDC workaround here https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/4177.

Yeah, you'll see I ended up using a custom setter to convert options from object to values - but this conversion to a JS object is not documented anywhere I know of

As per the documentation of lightning-datatable, Inline editing is not supported for date and location fields.
The standard data types are supported into the Columns of datatable:

action
boolean
button
button-icon
currency
date
date-local
email
location
number
percent
phone
text (default)
URL

You can define the custom datatype for the picklist. Similar to a standard data type, you can make a custom data type editable.

That custom data type editable link is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!
